# Develop R$$ population in SimCity4

Tags: simcity-4

I want to develop city with only mid-wealth population, little R$ and with jobs I-M industry and Co§§. Can anyone explain to me what R$$ wants? What is their demand? I'm trying to find it, but I need help. I only get R$ population high RCI demand, but not R$$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secret is education level (EQ).

When you start a new region, there will only be residential demand for R$. You need to raise the EQ by building schools and libraries so that the R$ sims will want to work at "better" jobs (such as manufacturing and commercial office).

When the manufacturing and commercial office (and eventually high tech industry) move in, they will want to hire R$$ sims, meaning that the demand for R$$ will increase.

[More details here](http://www.wiki.sc4devotion.com/index.php?title=Tutorial:Workforce_and_Occupation_Demands)

Comment: Thx, that is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

For mid-wealth residents, you need to provide the residential areas with *education* and *health* services available as well as zoning low-density areas.

You also need jobs that the mid-wealth will accepts (e.g. commercial, not service or dirty industry).

Comment: Ok, what level of education do I need to provide? I have elementary schools now with one library. My primary goal for that city is to have IM in it. Does R$$ work in IM or R$? That is confusing for me.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a couple of regions already you can just raise the taxes for the categories you do not want. And lower the one you want slightly (or raise it in the neighboring regions). The sims of your choice will migrate to your city while the ones you do not want stay away due to high taxes.

Remember to make the life of your sims better they need work nearby so you need to have an acceptable tax rate for it's corresponding C and I. Specifically for $$ they want at least the basic services, education and healthcare.